# Error Refreshing Gradle in Android Studio - Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, gradle

I have a problem with Gradle building. When I build my project, it displays the error: “Finish can only be called once in android studio”  i m using Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: try `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your android studio, try:

`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

ie, inside the `File` option, click on the `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` option.